# Galois conjugate $\sigma(a) = \Re(a)$ implies $\sigma(a) = a$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $a$ be a complex number which is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\sigma(a)$ be a [Galois conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_element_(field_theory)) of $a$, and let $\Re(a)$ be the real part of $a$.

**Question**: Is it true that $\sigma(a) = \Re(a)$ implies $\sigma(a) = a$?

Comment: For the real part of $a$ to make sense, you need that $a\in \mathbb C.$ In the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q,$ there are many embeddings into $\mathbb C.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I just clarified the post according to your comment. I hope that everything is fine now.

Comment: If there is a counterexample, it has to be in a non-Kroneckerian field (see [this math.overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203012/when-complex-conjugation-lies-in-the-center-of-a-galois-group) ), as CPCH's (now deleted) argument shows that the answer is affirmative if $\sigma$ commutes with complex conjugation.

Comment: Equivalently, can an irreducible polynomial $f$ have a real and a complex root with the same real part? Good question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbf{Q}$. I claim that $f(x)$ cannot have three distinct roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ such that

$$\alpha + \beta = 2 \gamma.$$

Assume otherwise. Let $L$ denote the splitting field. Since the Galois group of $L$  acts transitively on the roots,
there exists an embedding of $L$ into $\mathbf{C}$ such that $|\gamma|$ has the largest absolute value. But then $|\gamma| \ge |\alpha|, |\beta|$, and from the triangle inequality we see that the inequality above cannot hold.

Now consider your question, namely, we have an algebraic number $\alpha$ which is conjugate to $\gamma = \mathrm{Re}(\alpha)$, and thus $\gamma$ also a root of the minimal polynomial $f(x)$ of $\alpha$. Moreover, the complex conjugate $\beta$ of $\alpha$ is also a root. But

$$\alpha + \beta = \alpha + \overline{\alpha} = 2 \mathrm{Re}(\alpha) = 2 \gamma.$$

From the above analysis this cannot happen if these are distinct, which forces $\alpha$ to be real, and hence $\alpha = \gamma$ as desired.

Comment: The embedding into $\mathbb{C}$ is fixed from the beginning. But the real part depends on the embedding. What you proved is that there exists an embedding such that the property holds (with the real part of this embedding). That does not prove that the property holds for the embedding fixed from the beginning (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux but the equality $\alpha + \beta = 2\gamma$ is independent of the chosen embedding. So if it holds with one embedding, it holds with all embeddings.

Comment: @Mathmo123: I see. Thanks!